# What is the URL to this Kubernetes service/pod/docker thing

Tags: kubernetes

I need to hard code the address of a couchDB instance to another server in my kubernetes cluster. I'm not super familiar with kubernetes but I know that IP will change each time the cluster is rebuilt or the pod is rebuilt. So I can't use that.

What is the URL to this kubernetes service/what should I hard code into my Server Docker Image so it will alway find the CouchDB server in the system. I think it will be in this format

```
<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<service-port>
```

[image: Picture of the interface]

```
# YAML for launching the server
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kino-couch
  labels:
    app: kino-couch
spec:
  serviceName: orderer
  # Single instance of the Orderer Pod is needed
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kino-couch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kino-couch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kino-couch
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5984
        # Image used
        image: dpacchain/development:dpaccouch
```

[image]

If "wget 172.17.0.2:5984" works what should "172.17.0.2" be replaced with

The following is not correct

wget kino-couch-0.couch-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5984

wget kino-couch-0.couch-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5984

wget kino-couch-0.kino-couch.default.svc.cluster.local:5984

wget kino-couch-0.kino-couchdb.default.svc.cluster.local:5984

wget kino-couch-0.kino-couchdb.svc.cluster.local:5984

Comment: You should make this value configurable and pass it as an environment variable.  If you hard-code a value you'll never be able to run this in a non-Kubernetes development environment, or run multiple installations in the same cluster.  The host name syntax you have is correct but you need to know the Service and Namespace names that go into it.

Comment: Did you manage to find solution and come to some conclusions ?

Comment: kino-couch:5984 was the answer

Answer (score 2):

For StatefulSet you need to create a [Headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) to be responsible for the network identity of the Pods proving stable DNS entries. Notice `clusterIP: None` in below example.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: couch-service
  labels:
    app: kino-couch
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5984
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: kino-couch
```

The statefulset need to refer to the above service in `serviceName`. So the statefulset yaml would look like below

```
# YAML for launching the server
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kino-couch
  labels:
    app: kino-couch
spec:
  serviceName: couch-service
  # Single instance of the Orderer Pod is needed
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kino-couch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kino-couch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kino-couch
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5984
        # Image used
        image: dpacchain/development:dpaccouch
```

Then as a client you can access it using `couch-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:5984` to connect to a any of the CouchDB pods.

If you want to connect to a specific pod then use `kino-couch-0.couch-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:5984`. This is typically needed for connecting the couchDB pods between themselves to create a cluster.

Comment: I need "kino-couch-0.couch-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<service-port>" exactly as it should be based upon the information. I have tried

wget kino-couch-0.couch-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5984

wget kino-couch-0.couch-service.default.svc.cluster.local:5984

wget kino-couch-0.kino-couch.default.svc.cluster.local:5984

wget kino-couch-0.kino-couchdb.default.svc.cluster.local:5984

wget kino-couch-0.kino-couchdb.svc.cluster.local:5984